# Co-occurrence graph from 8 million rows of data

Tags: php, python, mysql, r

I have 8 million unique user_id to item_id pairings that look like this:

```
user_id     item_id
 1           item10
 1           item11
 1           item12
 1           item13
 2           item11
 2           item13
 2           item14
 2           item15
 3           item10
 3           item14
 3           item18
```

And I would like to get this into following format: node1,node2,weight where all the nodes are user_ids, and the weight between them are the amount of item_ids they share. So, for example, 1 and 2 are connected, since they share 2 item_ids [item11 and item13], and 1 and 3 share 1 item_id [item_10], 2 and 3 share 1 as well...etc.

```
1,2,2
1,3,1
2,3,1
```

would be the final result I am looking for. However, I have 8 million rows (around 25 unique user_ids, but many connections) what would be the most efficient way to do this? An SQL query I used to retrieve a similar (but not identical) network from around 50.000 rows took ages, so I am looking for alternatives. I can do it in R, php, sql or python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT node1.user_id, node2.user_id, COUNT(item_id)
FROM yourtable AS node1
JOIN yourtable AS node2 ON
    (node1.user_id <> node2.user_id) AND (node1.item_id = node2.item_id)
GROUP BY node1.user_id, node2.user_id
```

?

Comment: Thank you! I have been running it for hours now, I know that it will be slow with this much data, and I did a "show processlist" which shows that it is currently "copying into tmp table", and time is about 12.000 seconds.  Do you know how I can tell whether it is still working or it is frozen?

Comment: it's going to take a while. you've got 8 million records, and you're self-joining against them. the join conditions will massively cut down on things, but it's still potentially 64 quadrillion record pairings.

Answer (score 0):

In R, after you read in your file as a data frame `dat`, perhaps something like this:

```
## create list of items split up and labeled by user_id
item_list <- split(dat$item_id, dat$user_id)
## create list of unique ID's
id_list <- as.character(unique(dat$user_id))
## find all combinations of 2 ID's
id_comb <- combn(id_list,2)
## iterate through all ID combinations, locate the item sets
## intersect and find the cardinality afterwards
result <- apply(id_comb, 2, function(x) 
                length(do.call(intersect, item_list[x]))
```